# How to change DNS records on my office 365 admin?

Tags: dns, office365, cname, office365-apps, a-records

My client has a Office 365 account.

I am developing a website for him but the website resides on my own webserver.

How can I change the DNS record on my client's Office 365 to redirect all website requests to my webserver?

Note that only web requests should be redirected. Email A record requests should be left pointing to ns1.bdm.microsoftonline.com.

Comment: Did you try playing with the domain tab on the left side navigation menu in the admin center

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just redirect on the DNS level, just adjust the DNS host to redirect to the desired URL.